# ImageSource, fromFile, fromResource, fromBase64 in Nativescript 7.0.0

Tags: nativescript-angular

from https://www.npmjs.com/package/tns-core-modules

The tns-core-modules package exists only for compatibility with older versions of NativeScript. It's recommended to use @nativescript/core now

My question is how will I use this mudules

```
import {ImageSource, fromFile, fromResource, fromBase64} from "tns-core-modules/image-source";
```

Without compatibility issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys.
I finally figured it out.

```
import { ImageSource } from "@nativescript/core";
```

and in my component I defined

```
let imageSource = new ImageSource();
```